# How to find and delete Binding from dynamically added and deleted UserControl

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a set of UserControl, which share the same business object (ViewModel), but only
display data from this in different way.

I select an active UserControl via combobox. Old UserControl I delete from StackPanel and add new UserControl.

```
    var uiElement = thisObject.EditorsContainer.Children.FirstOrDefault();
    if (uiElement != null)
    {
        thisObject.EditorsContainer.Children.Remove(uiElement);
        uiElement.Cast<UserControl>().ClearValue(DataContextProperty);
    }
```

EditorsContainer is the StackPanel

It looks like a parent control keeps reference on the deleted control, because when I edit value in active control, the binding to binded property updates deleted control in memory.

Comment: Are you registering to handle any events on the deleted control that you are handling in the parent control and never unregistering from? This would create an implicit reference that would keep the control from being garbaged collected. If so you will have to explicitely unhook the events or look into the weak event pattern.

Comment: No, I don't register events, but each control has a binding. I can see how bindings work via tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround I have implemented an interface IActiveAware with IsActive property, which is false when the logical life of user control has ended. On the bound property in ViewModel I check this property.